# $\sin(x)$ is continuous at $x = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry

I need to test this and I don't understand how the first part is related to the second part. "Use the identity $|\sin(x)|<|x|$ when $0<|x|<\pi/2$, to show that $\sin(x)$ is continuous
at $x = 0$."

Let f : A → R be a function and a ∈ A. We say that f is continuous at x = a, if and only if the following three properties hold: 1-f(a) is defined (exists) 2-lim x→a f(x) exists 3-lim x→a f(x) = f(a). I know that sin(0)=0 so it is defined, lim x→0 sin(0)=0 so lim x→0 sin(0) = sin(0) so sin(x) is continuous at x=0 but I don't know how it relates to identity |sin(x)|<|x| when 0<|x|<π/2

Comment: This is obviously an exercise. Please share first your thoughts.

Comment: What's the definition of continuity that you use?

Comment: Let f : A → R be a function and a ∈ A. We say that f is continuous at x = a, if and only if the following three properties hold: 1-f(a) is defined (exists) 2-lim x→a f(x) exists 3-lim x→a f(x) = f(a). I know that sin(0)=0 so it is defined, lim x→0 sin(0)=0 so lim x→0 sin(0) = sin(0) so sin(x) is continuous at x=0 but I don't know how it relates to identity |sin(x)|<|x| when 0<|x|<π/2

Comment: Above you write $\lim_{x\to0}\sin(0)=0$. No, _that_ limit has nothing to do with anything. You need to show that $\lim{x\to0}\sin(x)=\sin(0)$. Which follows from $|\sin(x)|\le|x|$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a student like you, and i don't know if it is correct but i hope it will help you:

We want to proove that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} \; \sin x=0$. In order to do this let's recolle :
$$(\forall \varepsilon>0) (\exists \delta_\varepsilon>0) ( |x|<\delta_\varepsilon\Rightarrow  |\sin x|<\varepsilon)$$

In other words it means, that for every $\varepsilon>0$ that you will choose we can choose a $\delta_\varepsilon$-neighboorhood of $0$ such that if $|x|<\delta_\varepsilon$ the following inequality holds: $|\sin x|<\varepsilon$. Let (we will test) $\delta_\varepsilon=\varepsilon$. Such $\delta_\varepsilon$-neighboorhood: $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ of course exists because once you choose some $\varepsilon>0$ you can use the value of $\varepsilon$ as you wish. It suffices now to see that for any $x$ from $\delta_\varepsilon$-neighboorhood i.e. $|x|<\varepsilon$ the inequality $|\sin x|<\varepsilon$ holds since $|\sin x|<|x|$. To be formal at the end we can assume that $|x|<\pi/2$ however this do not change anything since $\delta_\varepsilon=\min\{\varepsilon,\pi/2\}$ can be taken if necessary.

Q.E.D

Comment: Why it has been down voted? Is there any error? If yes where?

Comment: That is a very nice answer that didn't deserve to be downvoted. However, the way you wrote it is very confusing. Straight to the point : for a given $\epsilon \in ]0; \pi/2[$, take $\delta := \epsilon$ and you get immediately what you wanted. $\forall x, \, |x|< \delta \Longrightarrow |\sin (x)| < \epsilon$. :)

Comment: @OlivierRoche Thank you but i wanted to be as didactic as possible to the op will understand all the processus.

Comment: @X0-user-0X that's good hoever your first answer was not clear. Olivier Roche correctly pointed out some things to  improve. From this reason I changed your answer but tried to conserve the spirit of your original thought.

Comment: I downvoted your answer not because I found something wrong with it, but because you were apparently doing someone's homework for them. Such questions must not be indulged. Look how other participants motivated the OP to work on the question and steered her in the right direction in the comments. I bet they had time and ability to answer the question equally well, but they did not do that. There is a lot of discussion on meta about assignment questions. In a nutshell, the site is for those genuinely interested in maths, not for homework freeloaders. Welcome and please be on the side of good!

Comment: Mh, I've been a bit dry indeed. What about $\forall x, \, |x - 0|< \delta \Longrightarrow |\sin (x) - 0| < \epsilon$ ? :)