# Prove the $\sin$ function is continuous at $0\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, continuity

I need to test this and I don't understand how the first part is related to the second part.

**Claim**

Use the identity $|\sin(x)| \leq |x|$ when $0 < |x| < \pi/2$ to show that $\sin(x)$ is continuous at $x = 0$.

**Definition**

Let $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function and $a\in A$. We say that $f$ is continuous at $x = a$ iff the following three properties hold:

- $f(a)$ is defined (exists),
- $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists,
- $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = f(a)$.

**Attempt**

I know that $\sin(0) = 0$ so it is defined, $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin(x) = 0$ so $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin(x) = \sin(0)$ so $\sin(x)$ is continuous at $x = 0$, but I don't know how it relates to identity $|\sin(x)| < |x|$ when $0 < |x| < \pi/2$.

**Question**

So my question is: how to relate the trigonometric identity with the continuity?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4455629/sinx-is-continuous-at-x-0/4455658#4455658

Comment: You want $$\lim_{x\to 0}\sin(x)=0.$$ Not $$\lim_{x\to0}\sin(0)=0.$$

Comment: Exactly, I'm sorry I made a mistake when writing it.

Comment: You’ve now corrected the statement of the limit, but you haven’t proven it, merely asserted it. Your argument would seem to work equally to prove any function is continuous at $0.$ Why is $\lim_{x\to0} \sin(x)=0?$ (Hint: here is where you use $\sin(x)|\leq x.$)

Comment: "I know that $\sin(0)=0$ so it is defined, $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin(x) = 0.$"  No, this reasoning is invalid.  Consider the following function $$f(x) = 0 ~: x ~\text{rational}~, f(x) = 1 ~: ~x ~\text{irrational}.$$  This is an example of a function that is defined everywhere, but where the limit as $x \to 0$ does not even exist.  So, the fact that the function exists at $x=0$ does not imply that the limit even exists, as $x \to 0$.

Comment: Consider a 2nd function: $$g(x) = 7 ~: ~x = 0, ~~g(x) = x ~: ~\text{otherwise}.$$  This is an example where the limit as $x \to 0$ does exist, but does not happen to equal $g(0)$.